Unable to remove column
I have deleted a column from my model class, but EF Core fails to recognize that it's been deleted. I will acknowledge that I'm making many other model changes at the same time, but I don't understand what I've done to get things out of sync.
The column in question is PdfTemplateId in my Company entity.
public class Company : ISoftDelete
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(120)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Code")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    //[Display(Name = "Default PDF Template")]
    //public int PdfTemplateId { get; set; }
    //public PdfTemplate PdfTemplate { get; set; }

    // Additional code...

}

public class CompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(c => c.Facilities)
            .WithOne(f => f.Company)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        builder.HasMany(c => c.Products)
            .WithOne(p => p.Company)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        builder.HasMany(c => c.Customers)
            .WithOne(c => c.Company)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}

But the property remains.

When I do a new add-migration, there are no changes. Below is part of my ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.
modelBuilder.Entity("PegasusEntities.Models.Company", b =>
{
    b.Property<int>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnType("int");

    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

    b.Property<string>("CompanyCode")
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(80)
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(80)");

    b.Property<DateTime?>("DeletedOnUtc")
        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

    b.Property<bool>("IsDeleted")
        .HasColumnType("bit");

    b.Property<bool>("IsLimited")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnType("bit")
        .HasDefaultValue(false);

    b.Property<string>("Name")
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(120)
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(120)");

    b.Property<int?>("PdfTemplateId")
        .HasColumnType("int");

    b.HasKey("Id");

    b.HasIndex("PdfTemplateId");

    b.ToTable("Companies", (string)null);
});

I tried uncommenting the deleted column, adding a migration, then deleting it again and adding another migration.
Unfortunately, I do not get a DropColumn in the second migration. I get the following migration instead.
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Companies_PdfTemplates_PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
        name: "PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies",
        type: "int",
        nullable: true,
        oldClrType: typeof(int),
        oldType: "int");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Companies_PdfTemplates_PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies",
        column: "PdfTemplateId",
        principalTable: "PdfTemplates",
        principalColumn: "Id");
}

Unfortunately, I'm really not sure how I can troubleshoot this and get things back in sync.
Update
I also tried adding a new column with the same name and a different type.
 public DateTime PdfTemplateId { get; set; }

Here is the output:
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10625]
The foreign key property 'Company.PdfTemplateId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'PdfTemplateId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10625]
The foreign key property 'Company.PdfTemplateId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'PdfTemplateId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.

And here is the migration.
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Companies_PdfTemplates_PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies");

    migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
        name: "IX_Companies_PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
        name: "PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies",
        type: "datetime2",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified),
        oldClrType: typeof(int),
        oldType: "int",
        oldNullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
        name: "IsLimited",
        table: "Companies",
        type: "bit",
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(bool),
        oldType: "bit",
        oldDefaultValue: false);

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
        name: "PdfTemplateId1",
        table: "Companies",
        type: "int",
        nullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Companies_PdfTemplateId1",
        table: "Companies",
        column: "PdfTemplateId1");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Companies_PdfTemplates_PdfTemplateId1",
        table: "Companies",
        column: "PdfTemplateId1",
        principalTable: "PdfTemplates",
        principalColumn: "Id");
}

Clearly, I still have some shadow properties going on here.
Update 2
Note that my PdfTemplates table does have a foreign key to my Companies table (a foreign key going the other way). So I wondered if this could be causing confusion. So I removed this and generated a new migration. In this case, it dropped the unneeded properties but then created a completely new table not in my code CompanyPdfTemplate. But I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing this.
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Companies_PdfTemplates_PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies");

    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_PdfTemplates_Companies_CompanyId",
        table: "PdfTemplates");

    migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
        name: "IX_PdfTemplates_CompanyId",
        table: "PdfTemplates");

    migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
        name: "IX_Companies_PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies");

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "CompanyId",
        table: "PdfTemplates");

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "PdfTemplateId",
        table: "Companies");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
        name: "IsLimited",
        table: "Companies",
        type: "bit",
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(bool),
        oldType: "bit",
        oldDefaultValue: false);

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "CompanyPdfTemplate",
        columns: table => new
        {
            CompaniesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            PdfTemplatesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_CompanyPdfTemplate", x => new { x.CompaniesId, x.PdfTemplatesId });
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_CompanyPdfTemplate_Companies_CompaniesId",
                column: x => x.CompaniesId,
                principalTable: "Companies",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_CompanyPdfTemplate_PdfTemplates_PdfTemplatesId",
                column: x => x.PdfTemplatesId,
                principalTable: "PdfTemplates",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_CompanyPdfTemplate_PdfTemplatesId",
        table: "CompanyPdfTemplate",
        column: "PdfTemplatesId");
}

Update 3
Since the PdfTemplates table might seem involved, below is my definition for that table.
/// <summary>
/// Represents a PDF template for generating custom PDF files.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This entity could be expanded to store PDF templates for other document types
/// in the future. Just add a new enum column to indicate the type.
/// </remarks>
public class PdfTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Delimiter used to combine replacement field names in <see cref="ReplacementFields"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ReplacementFieldDelimiter = "||";

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Company")]
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType("NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Template { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the names of all replacement fields in the document.
    /// This can be used to improve efficiency of validation replacement fields.
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(512)]
    public string ReplacementFields { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>
    /// Signifies this template is a default template. For example, this property
    /// is true for templates that were copied from the system defaults when a
    /// new company is created.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// Templates with this property set to true are displayed in the list of truck
    /// templates on the Edit Purchase Order page, in additional to the templates
    /// associated with purchase orders with <see cref="PurchaseOrder.IsBolTemplate"/>
    /// set to true.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Signifies this template is for trucks that arrive loaded (inbound loaded).
    /// If false, this template is for trucks that arrive empty (outbound loaded).
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsInboundLoaded { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PdfTemplateField> PdfTemplateFields { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class PdfTemplateConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PdfTemplate>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PdfTemplate> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(t => t.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.PdfTemplates)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        // Deleting PdfTemplate does not delete PurchaseOrder
        builder.HasMany(t => t.PurchaseOrders)
            .WithOne(o => o.PdfTemplate)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        // Deleting PdfTemplates does deletes PdfTemplateFields
        builder.HasMany(t => t.PdfTemplateFields)
            .WithOne(f => f.PdfTemplate)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}


Are there any pending migrations which are not applied? Can you try running update database and see what it shows? Or add manually if nothing helps…..protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
name: "PdfTemplateId",
table: "Companies");
}

@VivekNuna: I had one unrelated migration, but went ahead and updated the database with that one to ensure everything was applied. Same result. The screenshot above showing the PdfTemplateId column shows the column is still there. I tried adding a new column with the same name. I added my results to the end of the question.

Can you add the EntityTypeConfiguration for PdfTemplate? I suspect somewhere in your configuration you have a .HasOne(...).WithOne() or .HasMany(...).WithOne() which is configuring the relationship with a FK on Company. If PdfTemplate has a Company then it should be a .HasOne(x => x.Company).WithMany()

@StevePy: I've appended that to my question. But I've been looking at that code for hours, so I'm not sure how it's involved.

@StevePy: D'oh!!! That was it. My definition includes the line public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }. That was the problem! Your question forced me to review what I missed. Thanks!

Yep, just beat me too it, both Company and Companies, Companies wanting a Template FK reserved on Company. :)
